# Is it possible to run pbuilder without root privileges?

Tags: root, privileges, pbuilder

I realize that setting up `pbuilder` requires root privileges, but does each invocation really require root privileges?

Is there any way of running `pbuilder` as a standard user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, copied from: [pbuilder](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder-doc/pbuilder-doc.html#pbuilder-uml).

It is possible to use user-mode-linux by invoking pbuilder-user-mode-linux instead of pbuilder. pbuilder-user-mode-linux doesn't require root privileges, and it uses the copy-on-write (COW) disk access method of User-mode-linux which typically makes it much faster than the traditional pbuilder.

User-mode-linux is a somewhat less proven platform than the standard Unix tools which pbuilder relies on (chroot, tar, and gzip) but mature enough to support pbuilder-user-mode-linux since its version 0.59. And since then, pbuilder-user-mode-linux has seen a rapid evolution.

The configuration of pbuilder-user-mode-linux goes in three steps:

1. [Configuration of user-mode-linux](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder-doc/pbuilder-doc.html#user-mode-linux-config)

   user-mode-linux isn't completely trivial to set up. It would probably be useful to acquaint yourself with it a bit before attempting to use rootstrap or pbuilder-user-mode-linux. For details, read `/usr/share/doc/uml-utilities/README.Debian` and the `user-mode-linux` documentation. (It's in a separate package, `user-mode-linux-doc`.)

   user-mode-linux requires the user to be in the uml-net group in order to configure the network unless you are using slirp.

   If you compile your own kernel, you may want to verify that you enable TUN/TAP support, and you might want to consider the SKAS patch.
2. [Configuration of rootstrap](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder-doc/pbuilder-doc.html#rootstrap)

   rootstrap is a wrapper around debootstrap. It creates a Debian disk image for use with UML. To configure rootstrap, there are several requirements.

   - Install the rootstrap package.
   - TUN/TAP only: add the user to the uml-net group to allow access to the network
     `adduser dancer uml-net`
   - TUN/TAP only: Check that the kernel supports the TUN/TAP interface, or recompile the kernel if necessary.
   - Set up `/etc/rootstrap/rootstrap.conf`. For example, if the current host is 192.168.1.2, changing following entries to something like this seems to work.

     ```
     transport=tuntap
     interface=eth0
     gateway=192.168.1.1
     mirror=http://192.168.1.2:8081/debian
     host=192.168.1.198
     uml=192.168.1.199
     netmask=255.255.255.0
     ```

   Some experimentation with configuration and running rootstrap ~/test.uml to actually test it would be handy.

   Using slirp requires less configuration. The default configuration comes with a working example.
3. [Configuration of pbuilder-uml](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/pbuilder-doc/pbuilder-doc.html#pbuilderumlconfig)

   The following needs to happen:

   - Install the `pbuilder-uml` package.
   - Set up the configuration file `/etc/pbuilder/pbuilder-uml.conf` in the following manner. It will be different for slirp.

     ```
     MY_ETH0=tuntap,,,192.168.1.198
     UML_IP=192.168.1.199
     UML_NETMASK=255.255.255.0
     UML_NETWORK=192.168.1.0
     UML_BROADCAST=255.255.255.255
     UML_GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
     PBUILDER_UML_IMAGE="/home/dancer/uml-image"
     ```
   - It needs to match the rootstrap configuration.
   - Make sure BUILDPLACE is writable by the user. Change BUILDPLACE in the configuration file to a place where the user has access.
   - Run `pbuilder-user-mode-linux create --distribution sid` to create the image.
   - Try running pbuilder-user-mode-linux build.

Extra comments in the link:

`pbuilder-user-mode-linux` emulates most of pbuilder, but there are some differences.

- pbuilder-user-mode-linux does not support all options of pbuilder properly yet. This is a problem, and will be addressed as specific areas are discovered.
- /tmp is handled differently inside pbuilder-user-mode-linux. In pbuilder-user-mode-linux, /tmp is mounted as tmpfs inside UML, so accessing files under /tmp from outside user-mode-linux does not work. It affects options like --configfile, and when trying to build packages placed under /tmp.

To run pbuilder-user-mode-linux in parallel on a system, there are a few things to bear in mind.

- The create and update methods must not be run when a build is in progress, or the COW file will be invalidated.
- If you are not using slirp, user-mode-linux processes which are running in parallel need to have different IP addresses. Just trying to run the pbuilder-user-mode-linux several times will result in failure to access the network. But something like the following will work:

<sub>untested</sub>

Comment: If Slirp works out of the box and doesn’t require root (for writing to /etc and adding your user to a group) to set up, why would anyone *not* use Slirp for this?