# apt without root or sudo?

Tags: apt, root, pbuilder

I want to use apt (or pbuilder) to build a package in user's home directory. The home directory has enough space to hold the package's source, its dependencies and binary output. But the apt  documents say that you have to be a root user (sudo) to use it.

It's frustrating, as the only way now I have at my disposal is to build the package from source or use the dpkg and in both cases, figure out dependencies manually, create the dir layout manually and install the built things manually. Now if I can do all these things manually, why the tool writers (apt) think that doing so using their tool (apt) is somehow more special/dangerous?

I don't want to use root privileges JUST to build and test a user-land package.

If I am NOT allowed to do anything outside my home dir then why NOT the apt or pbuilder type commands be allowed to "build" something in my home dir without root privileges? I just want to use their functionality.

I have seen [Is it possible to run pbuilder without root privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54262/is-it-possible-to-run-pbuilder-without-root-privileges), but I don't want to use UML.

Comment: well, the link you provided gives you a solution. The solution runs without root and will resolve dependencies. Pick your poison ;)

Comment: Yes, it gives a solution but is this THE ONLY solution too? I mean a solution that comes prepackaged with poison can hardly be a solution. anyway thanks.